# How can I select a variable that matches the result of a subquery with multiple variables in SQL Server for a procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to obtain a list of products with a date that match the result of a subquery that returns the month with the most sales (All products most have the same month). The subquery I created to get that result takes more than one argument in consideration so the functions in , inside and exists don't work on it. Also I could not find a way to do this inside the function of join. I have run out of ideas.

```
create procedure [Prducts from the most profitale month] 
as
begin
    select 
        pr.Name, month(soh.OrderDate) as [Month]
    from 
        Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh
    join 
        Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod on sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
    join 
        Production.Product as pr on sod.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    where 
        month(soh.OrderDate) in (select top 1 month(soh.OrderDate) as [Month], sum(sod.OrderQty) as [Quantity]
                                 from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as soh
                                 join Sales.SalesOrderDetail as sod on soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
                                 join Production.Product as pr on pr.ProductID  = sod.ProductID
                                 group by month(soh.OrderDate)
                                 order by 2 desc) 
    group by 
        pr.Name, soh.OrderDate
end
```

Comment: Your `where` clause is all wrong. You have `where month(...) in  (.....)` but then in the subquery, you're returning **TWO** values from the `select` - that won't work! You need to select **ONLY** the months in your subquery - if you want to do a `in (....)` operation on it!!

Comment: "returns the the months " indicates **multiple** months but "[Prducts from the most profitale month]" implies a single month. Your query logic attempts to use both IN and "top 1" - which are also contradictory. Suggest you first decide on your goal. Then start thinking about your goal and your data. Actual data exists (or can exist) across **years**. Your query must determine monthly profit based on year and month - not just month.

Comment: Yes the tricky thing I can not figure is out how to make the dates in my query to match the return date in my subquery (I only care about the top 1 month).